# What is a good replacement for Visual Studio for developing Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: windows, android, c#, ide, visual-studio

I wanted to dive in to `Xamarin.Forms` for cross-platform developing with `C#` but I am using my PC for development for the time being and Visual Studio turned out to be requiring much more space than I anticipated, and some of it on System Drive even.

So my question is, can I develop projects in another IDE?

The replacement must have deployment for android systems, and would be nice to have for deployment option for windows, and ios as well.

## Specs:

1. Must run on web or Windows 7 with 4GB ram
2. Must have less than 2GB 'System Drive' size occupation requirement and less than 60GB overall size requirement
3. Must be able to deploy for android and ideally also for Windows and IOS.
4. Must be free
5. Ideally lightweight

---

Edited for clarification thanks to suggestion from [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy) in the comments.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software (in your case probably web-apps), please see [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what details are needed so we can give good recommendations, e.g. what features do you need, how much money you're willing to invest if it comes to paid solutions, etc.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at Mono on your machine. I am not sure of the exact space requirements. Mono develop is a lot smaller and less prone  to installation errors than VS. http://www.monodevelop.com/

Comment: My MonoDevelop takes up only 33MB on the disk, however there aren't any Xamarin Add-ins in the MonoDevelop Add-in Manager.

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft, can compile for gcc-7, python, java, and many more...